# Regex - Find all lines with x letters

Tags: regex

How can I select all lines with x letters? E.g.

```
   A
    12Foo_
    Albania
    Austria
    Azerbaijan
    B
    Bahamas
    Bahrain
    Burundi
    C
    Cabo Verde
    Cambodia
    Cameroon
```

**Example:**

How would I select every line with one letter, e.g. the regex should only select A,B and C in this case.

I tried it like this:

```
\S{1}\n
```

but this selects any single character at the end of the line.

[Online Regex](https://regex101.com/r/rW0zlf/2)

Comment: `\b[A-Z]\b` would do it.

Comment: /S matches non-space, use `\w`

Comment: @sweaver2112, what if there are numbers in the line? I need `\S` i think

Comment: `\w` matches numbers, letters, and underscore.

Comment: @AlexK., your regex does only work if there are no numbers in the line and also we cannot specify the amount of chars.

Comment: (Hint for me: `^\s*[\w]{9}\s*$`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should suit your needs (with the multiline option, i.e `^` and `$` match start/end of line):

```
^[^\S\r\n]*(?:\S[^\S\r\n]*){11}[^\S\r\n]*$
```

`11` being the number of chars you want.

See https://regex101.com/r/RNGT6w/1

Comment: Note that `\s` includes `\r` and `\n`, thus these dirty classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this works:

```
^[A-Z]
```

Comment: It does only work if we talk about one letter and if it is not a number or a char like !, ?, _, - ... and if it does not start with whitespaces.